# How to calculate a sliding Max Drawdown over a range of instruments in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good morning,

I am trying to build a stored procedure to compute a sliding maximum drawdowwn on every date over a range of 3 years on a large number of instruments using a sliding windows of 30 calendar days.

To that purpose, I use the following variables as entries :

```
@DateDebut datetime,
@DateFin datetime,
@ReturnPeriod int
```

My source table for prices is as below

```
create table #tmpPrix
(
    InstrumentID int not null,
    DatePrix datetime,
    Prix float
)
```

I then have the following structure to help me store my computation and visualize my results

```
create table #tmpCalculDD
(
    InstrumentID int not null,
    BoPDate datetime,
    BoPPrice float,
    EoPDate datetime,
    EoPPrice float,
    CurrentMinEoPPrice float,
    CurrentMaxEoPPrice float,
    CurrentSubsequentMinEoPPrice float,
    CurrentDD float,
    CurrentMaxDD float,
    IsNewPeak bit,
    IsNewValley bit,
    tmpDatePeak datetime,
    tmpDateValley datetime
)
```

From there I moved on to data insertion for prices, products id and dates :

```
insert into #tmpCalculDD (InstrumentID, EoPDate, EoPPrice)
select InstrumentID, DatePrix, Prix from #tmpPrix

update #tmpCalculDD set
    BoPDate = c.MinDate
from #tmpCalculDD 
    inner join (
        select a.InstrumentID, max(a.DatePrix) as MinDate, b.DatePrix
        from #tmpPrix as a 
        inner join #tmpPrix as b on (a.InstrumentID = b.InstrumentID and a.DatePrix <= DATEADD(day, @ReturnPeriod, b.DatePrix)) 
        group by a.InstrumentID,b.DatePrix) as c on (#tmpCalculDD.InstrumentID = c.InstrumentID and #tmpCalculDD.EoPDate = c.DatePrix)

update #tmpCalculDD set
    BoPPrice = b.Prix
from #tmpCalculDD
    inner join #tmpPrix as b on (#tmpCalculDD.InstrumentID = b.InstrumentID and #tmpCalculDD.BoPDate = b.DatePrix)
```

Next step is to compute current sliding min and max prices :

```
update #tmpCalculDD set
    CurrentMaxEoPPrice = a.CurrentMaxPrice,
    CurrentMinEoPPrice = a.CurrentMinPrice
from #tmpCalculDD inner join (
    select InstrumentID, EoPDate, 
    MAX(EoPPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY InstrumentID ORDER BY EoPDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as CurrentMaxPrice,
    MIN(EoPPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY InstrumentID ORDER BY EoPDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as CurrentMinPrice
    from #tmpCalculDD) as a on (#tmpCalculDD.InstrumentID = a.InstrumentID and #tmpCalculDD.EoPDate = a.EoPDate)
```

I then decided to identify new peaks and new valleys - since drawdown is computed as max peak to subsequent valley for every day of computation

```
update #tmpCalculDD set
    IsNewValley = a.NewValley,
    IsNewPeak = a.NewPeak
from #tmpCalculDD inner join (
    select InstrumentID, EoPDate, 
    CASE WHEN CurrentMinEoPPrice < LAG(CurrentMinEoPPrice, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION By InstrumentID ORDER BY EoPDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As NewValley,
    CASE WHEN CurrentMaxEoPPrice > LAG(CurrentMaxEoPPrice, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY InstrumentID ORDER BY EoPDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As NewPeak
    from #tmpCalculDD) as a on (#tmpCalculDD.InstrumentID = a.InstrumentID and #tmpCalculDD.EoPDate = a.EoPDate)
```

I moved on to the computations of the temp peak and valley dates

```
update #tmpCalculDD set
    tmpDatePeak = b.MinDate
from #tmpCalculDD 
    inner join (
    select a.InstrumentID, a.EopPrice, min(a.EoPDate) as MinDate from #tmpCalculDD a group by a.InstrumentID, a.EoPPrice) as b 
    on (#tmpCalculDD.InstrumentID = b.InstrumentID and #tmpCalculDD.CurrentMaxEoPPrice = b.EoPPrice) 

update #tmpCalculDD set
    tmpDateValley = b.MinDate
from #tmpCalculDD 
    inner join (
    select a.InstrumentID, a.EopPrice, min(a.EoPDate) as MinDate from #tmpCalculDD a group by a.InstrumentID, a.EoPPrice) as b 
    on (#tmpCalculDD.InstrumentID = b.InstrumentID and #tmpCalculDD.CurrentMinEoPPrice = b.EoPPrice)
```

And I am currently stuck, as I cant find a proper way to order my data in a chronological order, such as my MinEopPrice should reflect only the max subsequent new lows only after a peak has occured, and once a new pick has settled in, i am stuck with computing a valley to peak ratio.

Please find below some data samples for your convenience.

[data](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AolOEMbcYA6UaXpEPhyn9Y14Kb0?e=hPj1rG)

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Nicolas